# How to properly inject a SemaphoreSlim in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency, semaphore

I want to understand how to apply SemaphoreSlim (or any other locker for concurrency) based on a header value.

So lets say I have an app used by multiple clients, and I want to limit some methods to just one call per client.

My main code would look like this:

```cs
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore;

public class(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
  this.semaphore = semaphore;
}

public async Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
  await this semaphore.WaitAsync()
  
  try
  {
    // await some async stuff
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to inject the SemaphoreSlim on the Program.cs with something like:

```cs
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> semaphores = new ();

internal static IServiceCollection ConfigureSemaphore(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services.AddScoped(provider =>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        string? clientId = (context.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["clientId"])?.ToString();
        return semaphores.GetOrAdd(clientId ?? "0", _ => new SemaphoreSlim(1));
    });
}
```

That way I know that each client will have its own Semaphore based on a clientId header.

Makes sense to me, but I'm sure I'm missing something because when I start the API, the first call works but the next ones with the same clientId header throws exceptions saying that the SemaphoreSlim is already disposed.

I understand the injection needs to be Scoped, since I need to check the header value for each request, but when switching it to Singleton the Semaphore instance wont be disposed at the end of the first call. This wont work because a Singleton injection would inject the same Semaphore for any clientId, which is not the idea.

So... What should I do to avoid the SemaphoreSlim being disposed?
Or... What would be the correct approach to limit the concurrency by client?

(I checked lock keyword but it wont work with async calls)

Comment: Scoped services will be disposed when the scope is disposed. And asp.net creates a scope per request. But perhaps what you really want is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/rate-limit?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Could help, but rate limiting would limit any call for any endpoint.
What I would like is to limit some specific portions of the code (validation plus db insertion, that could have issues with concurrency)

Comment: @JosueDavidLimaGarcia if you want to limit request based on client id you can use my nuget packages which is working with action filters: https://github.com/sa-es-ir/DotNet.RateLimit

Comment: Optimistic database concurrency is usually implemented by adding a version number column to each table. That way you don't care at all how those database records are updated, or how many web servers you are running.

Comment: Some of those rate limiting examples will limit requests per user (or authentication token). But is that the right limit? Are all your database records unique per-user?

Comment: For the moment is just a simple local console application, Im just trying to get some improvement ideas for a bigger project with multitenant dbs and multiple web servers.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, the DI container is disposing your `SemaphoreSlim` when the request ends and you end up with a cached disposed instance. I would change the design as to not have a concrete `SemaphoreSlim` injected but rather some provider type interface.

```cs
public interface ISemaphoreSlimManager
{
    SemaphoreSlim Get(string clientId);
}

public class SemaphoreSlimManager : ISemaphoreSlimManager
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> Semaphores = new();
    public SemaphoreSlim Get(string clientId)
    {
        return Semaphores.GetOrAdd(clientId ?? "0", _ => new SemaphoreSlim(1));
    }
}
```

register it as a singleton

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ISemaphoreSlimManager, SemaphoreSlimManager>();
```

and then in your controller do something like:

```cs
var semaphore = _semaphoreSlimManager.Get(HttpContext?.Request.Headers["clientId"])?.ToString();
```

The reason why I'm not injecting an `IHttpContextAccessor` into `SemaphoreSlimManager` is because that is a general utility class that should theoretically work without it having to be in the context of an ASP Core app.

Comment: This works, not as I expected but it works
I tried to get rid of clientId variables on my service/repository layers but seems like there is no choice